# Make subdirectories based on lookup table string match

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to create subdirectories inside those directories only that **match a string in a lookup table**. Is it doable with `os.path.join`?

For example, inside those directories of the cwd that **end with** `=d5`, `=g7`, or `=a9` there should be two directories created: `_raw_files`, and `_sup_files`. How can I point `os.path.join` to make this **based on a lookup table** string (e.g., `config['g7']`...)?

Structure **before** and **after** the creation of directories:

```
CWD                                      
    01_camdirab=d5                       #<--create new dirs inside this
          /subdirs/.nef,.jpg,.avi
    02_camdirxyz=g7                      #<--create new dirs inside this
          /subdirs/.cr2,.jpg,.mp4
    03_camdire012345=a9                  #<--create new dirs inside this
          /subdirs/.mp4,.jpg,.avi
    04_camdire012345                     #<--DO NOT create new dirs inside (no string) this
          /subdirs/.mp4,.jpg,.avi


CWD
    01_camdirab=d5                       
          /_raw_files
          /_sup_files
          /subdirs/.nef,.jpg,.avi
    02_camdirxyz=g7                    
          /_raw_files
          /_sup_files
          /subdirs/.cr2,.jpg,.mp4
    03_camdire012345=a9                  
          /_raw_files
          /_sup_files
          /subdirs/.mp4,.jpg,.avi
    04_camdire012345                     
          /subdirs/.mp4,.jpg,.avi
```

My code and lookup table:

```
import os.path

config['g7']['append_dir_to_filename'] = 1; 
config['g7']['device_name'] = 'Canon-G7';
config['g7']['raw_file'] = array('cr2', 'jpg', 'mp4');   
config['d5']['append_dir_to_filename'] = 1; 
config['d5']['device_name'] = 'Nikon-D5';
config['d5']['raw_file'] = array('nef', 'jpg', 'avi');
config['a9']['append_dir_to_filename'] = 1; 
config['a9']['device_name'] = 'Sony-alpha-a9';
config['a9']['raw_file'] = array('mp4', 'jpg', 'avi');

def createDir(path):
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.mkdir(path)

dirs_name = os.listdir(cwd)
for dir_name in dirs_name:
    for key_word in config:
        if dir_name.endswith(key_word):
            _raw_files = os.path.join(cwd, dir_name, r'_raw_files')
            _sup_files = os.path.join(cwd, dir_name, r'_sup_files')
            createDir(_raw_files)
            createDir(_sup_files)
```

Comment: Please post your desire output. The function os.listdir may help.

Comment: Updated with output. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def createDir(path):
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.mkdir(path)

import os
cwd = os.getcwd()

config = {
    'g7': {},
    'd5': {},
    'a9': {},
}    
config['g7']['append_dir_to_filename'] = 1
config['g7']['device_name'] = 'Canon-G7'
config['g7']['raw_file'] = ('cr2', 'jpg', 'mp4')
config['d5']['append_dir_to_filename'] = 1
config['d5']['device_name'] = 'Nikon-D5'
config['d5']['raw_file'] = ('nef', 'jpg', 'avi')
config['a9']['append_dir_to_filename'] = 1
config['a9']['device_name'] = 'Sony-alpha-a9'
config['a9']['raw_file'] = ('mp4', 'jpg', 'avi')

dirs_name = os.listdir(cwd)
for dir_name in dirs_name:
    for key_word in config:
        if dir_name.endswith(key_word):
            _raw_files = os.path.join(cwd, dir_name, r'_raw_files')
            _sup_files = os.path.join(cwd, dir_name, r'_sup_files')
            createDir(_raw_files)
            createDir(_sup_files)
```

Comment: Thank you. I am trying it out but getting the error (my bad): `NameError: name 'config' is not defined`. How I make this lookup table to be recognized by the script? I inserted into the original question the code I am running.

Comment: You rule! Works like a charm! Thank you!